# Determine what Apache uses for APACHE_LOG_DIRECTORY at runtime?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server

I'm troubleshooting a SSL/TLS issue for Apache2 on Ubuntu Linux. The Apache configuration file is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. The file states it uses `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log` to log errors.

Searching with `find /opt -name error.log` is returning 0 results.

I would like Apache to tell me what the value of `APACHE_LOG_DIR` is. How do I tell Apache to evaluate its configuration files and then tell me the value of `APACHE_LOG_DIR` after evaluation?

---

Related: it does not appear that [apachectl](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html) provides the information (if the information in the man page is accurate).

Answer (score 2):

*By default Apache logs the messages under the directory location below*

> /var/log/apache2

You have to be a superuser in order to navigate to the directory.

Comment: Thanks Rule Breaker. How do I tell Apache to evaluate its configuration files and then tell me the value of `APACHE_LOG_DIR` after evaluation? There are other variables from the CONF files I am interested in, too.

Comment: You can use `mod_perl` and some bit of research. `$Apache->server->error_log` should contain the info you initially asked for. Maybe re-ask @server-fault (not superuser) "how to configure mod_perl to dump Apache's configuration parameters to a file." First see http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/apache_mod/113.htm#BIN236 followed by http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/apache_mod/129.htm#BIN268

Answer (score 1):

If no better answer, set up the `server-info` module, allow it for the localhost, and do a `wget` / `curl` on the URL and parse the output for the configuration parameters.

Comment: is it possible to have `server-info` write to the physical file system (rather than the server's virtual file system), and then copy the file? I'm having trouble with the server, so I don't really want to interact with it. If so, please provide instructions to do so and I'd be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The `server-info` module presents a URL which you can fetch using any HTTP client.  So it can be retrieved remotely (at some security risk) or "locally" on the server itself. But it will require a configuration change (probably) to access remotely.

Comment: *"I don't understand your question..."* - for example, at start-up (or during configuration change), `server-info` will write its information to the real file system using `${APACHE_LOG_DIRECTORY}/server-info.log`. And not the server's virtual file system, like `http://example.com/<some subordinate path>`.

Comment: In whatever startup script, you use `curl` and pipe that through `awk` or whatever, which determines the log directory and writes its output there. Can't write the script for you because I don't have an apache server in front of me and there's a few variables on your end.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. Is the answer NO, `server-info` cannot write to a file in the file system (like in `APACHE_LOG_DIRECTORY`)?

Comment: The answer is NO, `server-info` does not itself write to the filesystem.  By accessing the URL, you get a configuration dump, but only after Apache has started.